# Convert Dictionary Values into Array in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know this question is simple but I couldn't get it.

I have a dataframe which is called **df_check** like the one below

[image]

I created a dictionary using the code block below

```
userdic = df_check.groupby('userid')['poiid'].agg(set).to_dict()
```

userdict output looks like below

```
print(userdic)
```

> {1337: {9943,   9996,   10202,   10616},  1339: {10202,   10725,
> 11601},  5: {9177,   9489,   10190,   10349},  54: {123,
> 4,
> ...

My goal is to get the values of each key but I have to take them as arrays because I will be working in for loop.

**My Solution to get the first key's values.**

```
dict2list = list(userdic.values())[0]
list2array= np.array(dict2list )
```

When I print **list2array**, I get the result as below.

[image]

**My expectation like this**

> [360448, 486401, 190984, 941599, ... ]

**but output like this**

> array({360448, 486401, 190984, 941599, ...},dtype=object)

Comment: you can just do `list(list(userdic.values())[0])`, right?

Comment: set is useful for removing duplicates in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aggregated into a set, your numpy array isn't actually an array. To get the list back you can do list(list2array.item()) and index on that

If you change your list(userdic.values())[0] to list(userdic.values()[0]), your initial list will actually be a list instead of a set and the array will get initiated properly

Comment: When I do print(list2array[0]) I want to see output is 360448 (please see question), I am getting "IndexError: too many indices for array"

Comment: The other try, when I do print(dict2list[0]) I want to see the output is again 360448 (please see question), I am getting TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: I see. Since you aggregated into a set, your numpy array isn't actually an array. To get the list back you can do `list(list2array.item())` and index on that

Comment: If you change your `list(userdic.values())[0]` to `list(userdic.values()[0])`, both your list and your array should work better

Comment: changed my answer to reflect the new information